# EF Core/SQL Join a different entity based on a condition

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, entity-framework-core

Lets suppose I have a table called Transactions

Transactions has the following columns

```
OrderId,
OrderType (Can be 0 = Sale or 1 = Purchase) <--- this can increase
Amount
```

Now I want to get the relevant data based on the OrderType
if `OrderType = 0` then join from `Sale Table else Join from Purchase Table`.

Currently what I am doing is that doing three calls to the database to get the some other values from the other tables(which works but highly inefficient in long run as 3 Calls are bad performance wise).

My solution is using left join with SQL

```
SELECT ap.*,
        coalesce(s.orderNo,p.orderNo) as orderNo
FROM apptransactions AS ap
LEFT JOIN sales AS s ON (ap.orderType = 0 and ap.orderId = s.id)
LEFT JOIN purchases AS p ON (ap.orderType = 1 and ap.orderId =  p.id);
```

how can this query be converted to EF Core?

Comment: *3 Calls are bad performance wise* - do you have proof of this, or is it an assumption?

Comment: EF will make LEFT joins anyway, if it thinks there might be 0 rows in the target. You can just use it like nomal/don't overthink it. Personally I think i'd split it to 2 queries (tran include sales where ordertype = 0, and tran include purchases where ordertype = 1).. But the code has a bit of a smell to it how it is currently; your one column in tran is FK'd out to multiple other tables. `orderId` should really be called `salesIdOrPurchaseIdDependingOnOrderTypeId`, and when you add a third, the name should get longer.. that's an indication that the data modelling has gone wrong

Comment: Your schema doesn't follow normal form. You probably want to use link tables between `Transactions` and `Sales`/`Purchases`. But its hard to say as I don't know your full dataset and use cases.

Comment: @CaiusJard what do you think is the best approach, add multiple columns? (SaleId,PurchaseId,etcId, etcId), wouldnt this cause alot of nulls in the row? because lets suppose I have three columns and in every row out of those three columns only one would have value?

Comment: what I am doing is that this is kind of a transaction log, which tracks all the transaction in a system in a single table and I differentiate it by two columns (OrderType,OrderId) and based on those two columns I find where this transaction belongs too, this might not be the best approach but I am open to ideas and suggestions.

Comment: And what is a transaction? How many sales are there in a transaction? How many purchases? Does a sale has-a transaction? Does a transaction has-a sale?

Answer (score 0):

Why is your query not like this?

```
var results = context.Transactions.Select(t => 
    new 
    { 
        /* t.column list, there's no t.* in LINQ */, 
        OrderNo = t.OrderType == 0 ? t.Sale.OrderNo : t.Purchase.OrderNo
    });
```

Let EF generate any underlying joins it needs to, concern yourself with getting the results you want.

This also alludes to what @caius mentions. Your model is likely not high level enough or incorrectly mapped.

Comment: what I am doing is that this is kind of a transaction log, which tracks all the transaction in a system in a single table and I differentiate it by two columns (OrderType,OrderId) and based on those two columns I find where this transaction belongs too, this might not be the best approach but I am open to ideas and suggestions.